# Pass extra parameters to silex error handler callback function

Tags: silex

I'm building an app with Silex and Twig where I have my route handlers defined in this way (standard way):

```
//routes.php
$app->get('/pageA',function () use($app){
  //Display something
});

$app->get('/pageB',function () use($app){
  //Display something
});

$app->post('/pageB',function (Request $req) use($app){
  //Process something
});
```

And then I have set up an error handler to manager possible errors that are thrown inside the route handlers, like this:

```
//routes.php
$app->post('/pageB',function (Request $req) use($app){
  //Do something, but an error occurs..
  $app->abort(404,"Page not found");
});

//errors.php
$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) use($app) {
  switch($code){
    case 404:
      return $app['twig']->render('404.twig',array('error'=>$e->getMessage()));
    //Other error codes...
    default:
      //return something
  }
});
```

What I would like to do is pass an extra parameter from the route handler to the callback function of the error handler, like this:

```
//routes.php
$app->post('/pageB',function (Request $req) use($app){
  //Do something, but an error occurs..
  $app->abort(404,"Page not found","My extra parameter");
});

//errors.php
$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code,$extra_param=null) use($app) {
  if(isset($extra_param))
    //Process the error in a different way
  else{ //Standard way
    switch($code){
      case 404:
        return $app['twig']->render('404.twig',array('error'=>$e->getMessage()));
      //Other error codes...
      default:
        //return something
    }
 }
});
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the most elegant solution but you could probably just add an array to `$app`.

```
$app['my_param_bag'] = array();

$app->get('/pageB', function(Request $request) use ($app) {
  $app['my_param_bag'] = array('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
  $app->abort(404, "Page not found");
});

$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) use($app) {
  error_log(print_r($app['my_param_bag'],1).' '.__FILE__.' '.__LINE__,0);

  if(!empty($app['my_param_bag'])) {
    // do something with the params
  }
  else{ 
    switch($code){
      case 404:
        return $app['twig']->render('404.html.twig',array('error'=>$e->getMessage()));
      default:
    }
  }
});
```

I'm not sure about how you have your application setup but for me I was able to add this empty array in a configuration file.

Comment: I definitely thought about this and I can definitely do this, but as you point out it's not the most elegant solution.

Comment: The first thing I looked into was the [abort](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/src/Silex/Application.php#L393) and [error](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/src/Silex/Application.php#L415) methods. That lead me to look at the [ExceptionListenerWrapper](https://github.com/silexphp/Silex/blob/1.3/src/Silex/ExceptionListenerWrapper.php#L53). It should be possible to extend the application instance and override or add the desired functionality. But at the end of the day why not just use an array in the application container? It's simple and gets the job done.